# Using SASS map function instead of variable interpolation

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to define (actually, overwrite) some SASS variables using a map, in place of what I normally would have done with variable interpolation. This is configuring a bootstrap theme, so I don't think I can effectively rewrite the downstream to use maps.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
$btn-default-color:              $color-text;
$btn-default-bg:                 $color-white;
$btn-default-border:             $btn-default-bg;

$btn-primary-color:              #fff !default;
$btn-primary-bg:                 $brand-primary !default;
$btn-primary-border:             darken($btn-primary-bg, 5%) !default;

$btn-success-color:              #fff !default;
$btn-success-bg:                 $brand-success !default;
$btn-success-border:             darken($btn-success-bg, 5%) !default;

$btn-info-color:                 #fff !default;
$btn-info-bg:                    $brand-info !default;
$btn-info-border:                darken($btn-info-bg, 5%) !default;

$btn-warning-color:              #fff !default;
$btn-warning-bg:                 $brand-warning !default;
$btn-warning-border:             darken($btn-warning-bg, 5%) !default;

$btn-danger-color:               #fff !default;
$btn-danger-bg:                  $brand-danger !default;
$btn-danger-border:              darken($btn-danger-bg, 5%) !default;
```

Instead, I'd like to create map like this, and run an `@each` loop instead:

```
$btn-colors-map: (
    default: (
        bg: $color-white,
        bg-hover: $color-ghost,
        border: $color-white,
        border-hover: $color-ghost
    ),
    primary: (
        bg: $color-white,,
        bg-hover: $color-ghost,
        border: $color-white,
        border-hover: $color-ghost
    )
)

// poor pseudo-code, sorry!
@each $key, $btn in $btn-colors-map {
    $btn#{$key}-color: $btn[bg];
}
```

But unfortunately the docs I've read on SASS maps are very technical, and provide little real-world examples on how to actually solve the var interpolation gap. I've yet to figure out how to make this actually work (or if it's even technically feasible).

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, I'm just trying to help, but have you looked into SASS's `map-get`? Maybe something like this: `#{map-get($btn, bg)}`?

Comment: Yeah read about that too, but the map docs really don't touch on how to work around variable interpolation from what I can see.

Comment: Ahh okay. I had just happened to see that in [this discussion](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/132#issuecomment-46554767) regarding variable interpolation in SASS which is why I made mention of it.