# Get value by name in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

We recently introduced **SASS** into our project and i am very new to it.

I have a ***color.scss*** file which contains the variable name and its value for all the colors used in the project.
I am having difficulty in remembering all the names of the colors.

Example,

`@include Font(arial,18px,#4a4a4a,left);`

I want to see what is the key for the value ***#4a4a4a***  i.e., if the type ***#4a4a4a*** , its corresponsing ***$variable*** name should show up.
Do we have a better way to do rather than, searching for ***#4a4a4a*** in ***color.scss*** file?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. You're saying you are using variables to store the color, but you can't remember the variable name, so you want to be able to use the color instead, **then insert the variable on compilation**, change it back to a color. Why don't you (1 just use colors or (2 just remember the variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you want to use something like a hash ,where in you would push color as the key and get the associated variable name.

You need to check to see sass maps

This could be helpful to you
https://www.viget.com/articles/sass-maps-are-awesome

and this
[Using SASS map function instead of variable interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664147/using-sass-map-function-instead-of-variable-interpolation)

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for something like this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've defined variable names for colors in that `colors.scss` file you're talking about, you can feed that variable name to your "Font" `@mixin` directly.

```
@include Font(arial, 18px, $colorName, left);
```

Assuming that `colors.scss` contains something like this, and is included before the file where you `@include` the mixin.

```
// colors.scss
$colorName: '#FF0000';
```

However, if you have a `map` of colors, like:

```
$colors: (red: '#FF0000', white: '#FFFFFF', blue: '#0000FF');
```

You could look up a key by a value by looping through the map, and matching the value to a key. This probably isn't what you're going for, but if it is, the below would be a good starting point for a mixin.

```
@each $name, $hex in $colors {
    @if ($hex == $suppliedColor) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Our designer provides #4a4a4a  value, I usually search in the color.scss file to know what variable name it has. 
So, instead of moving between two files, is there a way where i can see the variable name in my current .scss file?